# Help with choosing structure of code to make NewsHandler class

Tags: php, oop, class, static-classes

Task is to add News on our site.

I'd like to make a php class for this task. This class should be able to do such things:

1. Add news
2. Edit news
3. Remove news
4. Display exact news
5. Get list of news

News can be of 3 types: local news (news of organizations registered on site), global news (news that add administration of the site), and stock (hot offers from organizations)

Help to choose correct class structure for such a task.
I thought, it can be a static class, for example *NewsHandler* that has static methods:

- **add** ($type_news, $title, $announcement, $content, $picture)

  (method will return the *id* of news)
- **edit** ($id, $new_title, $new_announcement, $new_content, $new_picture)
- **remove** ($id)
- **display** ($id)
- **getAll** ($type_news) (method will return the list of **id**'s of news)

This is very trivial approach. Is this wrong? May be I should do bigger class structure - with inheritance? For example:

- static class *NewsHandler*
- class *News* (that produces News instances)
- classes *LocalNews*, *GlobalNews*, *Stock* (extending from *News*)

If so, I don't know which methods each of them should have

Comment: I think you'll need a lot more than just one class, or at least you should, and this class would only be an API one for all theses classes

Comment: as example #2 from my post? there is approximative scheme, but how to distribute methods for these classes?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that, in quite simple terms, this would be an okay setup. However, as pointed out in the comments, you probably need more than these classes. OOP is very much top-down thinking, where you first have to oversee what all the stuff is you're going to do. For instance, the news probably has to be stored in a database. So: database class. And you might want to use some sort of validation, eg. validation class. Then there's rendering the stuff. Throw in a couple of classes for those, for templating, formatting etc.
As you can tell, your news classes are going to use all these other classes. So, while your setup looks okay from the news point of view, there's bound to be a lot more around it. And that's why there's no clear and simple answer to your question.

Comment: thanks for answer. Yes, now, after some little experience I understand this - that OOP approach requires more classes than it seems to be =)